# Как писать программы для MSVS 2008

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

Есть 3 сборки игрового движка в .exe файлах, для VS 7.0 , 8.0 , 9.0(позже нету). Я скачал самую последнюю для 9.0. Выяснил что это VS 2008 года. Но официального пакета что бы её скачать не нашел. Предположил что можно как то на самой последней VS писать программы для VS 2008. Вопрос: **Как это сделать?** И можно ли вообще так делать? P.S. Если что то не понятно объяснил, могу пояснить в комментариях.

Comment: Поддержка VS 2008 скоро истекает (или уже истекла), но вот эта ссылка вроде пока работает: https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso Насчет использования тулсета VS 2008 на более новых VS, посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775363/how-to-build-with-v90-platform-toolset-in-vs2012-without-vs2008-using-windows-s?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо!